# Php mostrar etiqueta img en echo

Tags: php, imagen

estoy tratando de mostrar los datos de un empleado; al final quiero mostrar su foto la cual está en el directorio donde está el archivo y tiene la extensión .jpg

```
echo 'Hora de salida '.$horaDeSalida.'<br>'.
            'Valor Hora '.$valorHora.'<br>'.
            'Salario básico '.$salarioBasico.'<br>'.
            'Porcentaje Recargo Diurno '.$porcentajeRecargoDiurno.'<br>'.
            'Horas diurnas '.$horasDiurnas.'<br>'.
            'Recargo diurno '.$recargoDiurno.'<br>'.
            'Porcentaje Recargo Nocturno '.$porcentajeRecargoNocturno.'<br>'.
            'Horas nocturnas '.$horasNocturnas.'<br>'.
            'Recargo nocturno '.$recargoNocturno.'<br><br>'.

            'Salario neto '.$salarioNeto.'<br>'.
            'Nombre '.$_GET['Nombre'].'<br>'.
            '<img src=".$_GET['Nombre'].'.jpg'" width='50' height='50' />';
```

Pero la última línea no me cuadra, me sale el error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Nombre' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: Sale esto: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''Nombre\'].'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting identifier (T_STRING)

Comment: `'<img src="'.$_GET['Nombre'].'.jpg" width="50" height="50" />';` Con eso no deberías tener problemas

Comment: Esa fue la solución... muchas gracias KacosPro

Comment: Considera aceptar una respuesta, para mas información te invito a leer [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

En PHP podemos declarar un string de varias maneras si necesitamos comillas en el, por ejemplo si necesitamos que un string contenga comillas dobles lo hacemos de esta manera `echo '"Hola"';` e imprimirá "Hola", lo mismo con las comillas simples `echo "'Hola'";` imprimirá 'Hola'.

Si necesitamos que se imprima una variable lo podemos hacer encapsulando todo con comillas dobles, por ejemplo

```
$var = 'Soy un texto';
echo "$var";
```

Nos dará como resultado: **Soy un texto**

Si queremos imprimir dos strings podemos hacer esto:

```
$var = 'Soy un texto';
$foo = ' Soy otro texto';
echo $var, $foo;
```

Que nos dará como resultado esto: **Soy un texto Soy otro texto**

Ahora tu problema es que estás mezclando varias cosas

```
'<img src=".$_GET['Nombre'].'.jpg'" width='50' height='50' />';
----------^
```

Hasta aquí todo bien, para PHP la comilla doble sigue siendo parte del string así que continua

```
'<img src=".$_GET['Nombre'].'.jpg'" width='50' height='50' />';
------------------^
```

Hasta que llega aquí, para PHP ahí estamos cerrando el string, por lo tanto espera que cerremos la linea con ";" o que pongamos otro string con una "," y es por eso el error tan descriptivo:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Nombre' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

#### Solución

Podríamos querer encapsular todo dentro de comillas dobles y aprovechar la declaración de la variable de esta manera

```
"<img src='$_GET['Nombre'].jpg' width='50' height='50' />";
```

Lo que nos funcionaría sí la variable no tuviera comillas simples para acceder a su índice, lo que nos llevaría de vuelta a los problemas anteriores.

Por lo que, la solución es concatenar la variable e imprimir la tag

```
'<img src="'.$_GET['Nombre'].'.jpg" width="50" height="50" />';
```

Notese que puse los números de `width` y `height` entre comillas dobles, ya que si no lo hago regresariamos al problema original.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que escapar las comillas simples asi:

```
echo 'Hora de salida '.$horaDeSalida.'<br>'.
        'Valor Hora '.$valorHora.'<br>'.
        'Salario básico '.$salarioBasico.'<br>'.
        'Porcentaje Recargo Diurno '.$porcentajeRecargoDiurno.'<br>'.
        'Horas diurnas '.$horasDiurnas.'<br>'.
        'Recargo diurno '.$recargoDiurno.'<br>'.
        'Porcentaje Recargo Nocturno '.$porcentajeRecargoNocturno.'<br>'.
        'Horas nocturnas '.$horasNocturnas.'<br>'.
        'Recargo nocturno '.$recargoNocturno.'<br><br>'.

        'Salario neto '.$salarioNeto.'<br>'.
        'Nombre '.$_GET['Nombre'].'<br>'.
        '<img src="'.$_GET['Nombre'].'.jpg" width="50" height="50" />';
```

Comment: Saca este error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''" width='' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: Si intento esto ya no sale error, pero no se ve la imagen: ?>

<img src="<?php echo '$_GET["Nombre"]'.'.jpg'; ?>" width="100" height="100" />

<?php

Comment: ya edite my respuesta, intentalo asi

Comment: Gracias a todos, ya me funciona

Answer (score 0):

El echo ha de estar definido en la misma linea sin saltos de linea en el código, prueba esto que te escrito...

```html
echo ('Hora de salida '.$horaDeSalida.'<br>'.'Valor Hora '.$valorHora.'<br>'.'Salario básico '.$salarioBasico.'<br>'.'Porcentaje Recargo Diurno '.$porcentajeRecargoDiurno.'<br>'.'Horas diurnas '.$horasDiurnas.'<br>'.'Recargo diurno '.$recargoDiurno.'<br>'.'Porcentaje Recargo Nocturno '.$porcentajeRecargoNocturno.'<br>'.'Horas nocturnas '.$horasNocturnas.'<br>'.'Recargo nocturno '.$recargoNocturno.'<br><br>'.'Salario neto '.$salarioNeto.'<br>'.'Nombre '.$_GET['Nombre'].'<br>'.'<img src=".$_GET['Nombre'].'.jpg'" width='50' height='50' />');
```